# Android FTP Library

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm looking for a java library that works on the android that can download and resume files from an FTP server.  Does anyone know of such a library.  I've found lots of client apps, but no stand alone libraries.

Comment: Did you read [this resource](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0404-ftp.html)? You can pick something from it.
Specifically [this page](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/ftp/jw-0404-ftptable.html).

Comment: So how about writing just an answer with that content?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try using [apache commons ftp](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName(server));
ftpClient.login(user, password);
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(serverRoad);
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

BufferedInputStream buffIn = null;
buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.storeFile("test.txt", buffIn);
buffIn.close();
ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Comment: I've started using apache commons ftp and it's a beaut.

Comment: very very inportant - active mode doesn't work on your android device.  You must enter passive mode.
so in between connect and login put this: 

    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

Comment: are you sure that there are apache comms ftp client api on android ?

Comment: @Reno i'm positive you can include the jar in your project and it will run with no issues. Have it working in several apps and it works great.

Comment: thanks for replying, I've already done this and its excellent. ^^ Oh and if you're not using this already, try out [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html) for shrinking the jar further. I highly recommend it.

Comment: i get `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` when invoking the `storeFile` command... :( how can i fix this?

Comment: There is also a nice [FTP client example at apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java).

Comment: For anyone looking at this years later, Apache Commons Net is working for me. Use `implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.6'` in build.gradle (Module: app) dependences.