# is it possible to create the connectivity of android with ftp server

Tags: android

is it possible to create the connectivity of android with ftp server. i am going to create  an application where login information about user is placed on ftp server.

Comment: See [Android FTP Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are [several libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library) that support Android.  However, you should be aware that FTP provides no security.  So I would be wary about using it for any kind of login information.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this library:
[commons-net-ftp](http://www.docjar.com/jar_detail/commons-net-ftp-2.0.jar.html)
and use [this](http://royvandewater.com/2010/10/uploading-a-file-to-ftp-with-android/) little example.
this will grant you the ability to make ftp connection (like filezila for example)
pay attention that you need to add to the menifest file(AndroidManifest.xml) the line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Good luck.