# how to make FTP connection in in Android?

Tags: android, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

hi, 
How can we implement an FTP client in android? as i want to upload image file from my android application using FTP

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)