# uploading and downloading data from ftp server in android

Tags: android, web-services, ftp, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

I am very much new to the android development, i wanted to upload a file from my android phone to the ftp server and later downloading a file from the ftp server . How to implement this one ,please help me out
thanks in advance

Comment: Check this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library) and see if it helps. There is a lot of help here on FTP with Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out although I believe this only works for uploading files. You may be able to modify it to download?

http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/

This is an external jar you would add to your project.