# FTP implement in android issue

Tags: android

i have refer [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library) for implement ftp upload file fundamental in android but when i click on http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html it get nothing. so how can i get jar file first?

after some time i got jar file name is "**commons-net.jar**" & "**org.apache.commons.net_2.0.0.v200905272248.jar**"
but not get sucess to import `import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;` class.

i have also refer site form  :: [**This Example**](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28) 
which recommended jar filen & also download but got same problem for me.

**Screen short** 
[image]

Comment: How do you include this jar into your Android project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons FTP client is part of Apache Commons Net library: http://commons.apache.org/net/download_net.cgi

Download the .zip, unpack it and use the .jar.

Comment: i put here screen short please see it

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project