# Importing a file from web

Tags: android

I have a file in txt-format saved on an ftp server. The server does not require a username or password.

I want to import this into my android app so that I can use the text and numbers from it.

How do I do this, or where can I find more information regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library) that you would have found if you searched for android ftp library in the search field up there.