# Where do I start for coding a connection to Filezilla in Android?

Tags: java, android, filezilla

I'm creating an app where you have to download a txt file online. This file is availible only on filezilla. Having looked around, I still have not found a concrete answer on where to start. I simply want to download this file,parse it and display data from it.

Comment: If you are trying to download file hosted on a ftp server (that's what you mean by mentioning "filezilla" I guess), then check out the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileZilla is an FTP client so you need to learn how to download a file using FTP. A file cannot only be available via FileZilla.