# Upload file to FTP

Tags: android, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to an FTP using apache commons ftp.
I am using a code that I have seen on several websites, including stackoverflow

[Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

The problem is that in the line:

```
Buffin = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (file));
```

I can not put any paths in "file", eclipse does not validate any values ​​or path-

What would have to indicate in "new FileInputStream"?

I do not know I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: What kind of object should be? The string is not validated

Answer (score 2):

You need a `File` object to pass it to the `FileInputStream`.

```
Buffin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file"));
```

And you can't `Upload file to FTP` because FTP is not a place, it is a protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Create a File object with the path and pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
`Buffin = new BufferedInputStream (new FileInputStream (<path to your file>));`

Details here:
[FileInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29)