# FTP Client for android?

Tags: android, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

Can anyone provide me a fully working code for a FTP Client for Android?

After searching I have found that there is no built in library for Android FTP.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking through open source repositories to give you a head start, which I assume you're looking forward.

Here's one I found in about a minute of searching https://github.com/samterer/AndroidFTP.  Looking at the implementation it looks like its in working condition but I have no idea really.  I'll leave that up to you. Be sure to give credit where credit is due in your work.

Comment: I can't find the library in this code fully. "TailerListenerAdapter" are not recognized.