# Matlab/simulink udp channel

Tags: android, matlab, udp, simulink

I have a Matlab/simulink logfile and I want to send the logfile to my android application. I think of building a simulink model to send this info as a UDP packet to a wireless router and then the router can broadcast it to Eclipse or my Tablet or whatever.
I should add that the android application needs realtime information (Matlab logfile).

Do you have any suggestions how can I do this ? or is it practically possible to do this cause I'm new in this field and dont have much information.

could I do this in any other way ? like writing a server in matlab to send information to router and a client in eclipse ?

I'm totally confused !

Comment: How much data are you talking about?

Comment: basically it's a logfile contianing some information that the android app will visualized . In wrost case I think it would be 2048byte in each moment.

Answer (score 0):

[Matlab natively supports ftp protocol](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ftpclass.html). [There exists a FTP server for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library), which could easily be imported to Android, and can be downloaded [from apache](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/). Set your Android device as an FTP server, send data from Matlab to the Android phone, and you're set.

Comment: should I use cable for sending data from matlab to android phone ? or it'll work with wireless too?

Comment: FTP use TCP but I need to transfer realtime data , so time is very important I need to use UDP .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UDP blocks available in [Simulink Support Package for Samsung GALAXY devices](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/android-programming-simulink.html) to send data from Simulink to your Android device.