# How can I list items on an FTP server in a list view? (Android)

Tags: java, android, ftp

Ok, so I'm learning Java and I can't figure out how to list and display the contents of an FTP server in a list view, and I want to be able to download the files too.

Please show me code snippets if you can, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

these are basically two different questions. 1. how to get data from FTP and 2. how to use a ListView.

the answer to nr. 1 can be found here on stackoverflow: [Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

for nr. 2, please refere to the android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), check the sample projects in the SDK or simply google for something like "android listview example".