# FTP upload Ftp get error: 553 Can't open that file

Tags: android, ftp

When i upload my image file through AndFtp am not getting any error,But when i upload my file through my own SimpleFTP am getting Ftp get error: 553 Can't open that file: Permission denied.Why its happening.Which is fast and efficient way to upload image for android.

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library