# Android - Image becomes empty when uploading to PHP server

Tags: php, android, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an img from an android phone to a php server.

But when it is uploaded its data is lost(the file exist but has 0 bytes)

I dont know if the problem is on the php side or the android side.

Here is the code I use upload

PHP:

```
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
?>
```

Java:

```
private  void httpPostFileUpload(String fpath){
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String pathToOurFile = fpath;
        Log.v("file path",fpath.toString());
        String urlServer = "http://leojg.alwaysdata.net/tests/androidConnect/upload_image.php";
        //String urlServer = "http://65.182.110.63/public/handle_upload.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        String fname = "";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        try
        {
            File f = new File(pathToOurFile);
            fname =  f.getName();

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            Log.v("ouput stream",outputStream.toString());              

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.d("amanda", "upload async finished, server response : " + serverResponseMessage);

            fileInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream = null;
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;
            f= null;



            parent.invokeJs("pictureUploadEnded('" + fname + "')");
            //this.delete(fpath);

        }
            catch (Exception ex)
        {
                Log.d("amanda", "exception uploading image : " + ex.getMessage());
        }     
}
```

Here you can see where the img is stored http://leojg.alwaysdata.net/tests/androidConnect/

SOLUTION:

```
<?php
$target_path = "./";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
 " has been uploaded";
} else{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get multipart/form-data from `$_REQUEST`. Try `$_FILES`. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: I changed but I have the same problem

Comment: @leojg - You can't just change `$_REQUEST` to `$_FILES`. You have to access the temporary file that PHP uploads (PHP tells you where that temp file is in the `$_FILES` array). Then, you can use `move_uploaded_file` to move it where you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks. I had to change all the code but now it works. I will post the fix above.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a must for you to use PHP upload? I always find FTP upload easier to implement (backend can use FileZilla) and more stable!

Comment: Yes it is. 

I did not know that you could use FTP to upload from android. I will try. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @leojg If i am not mistaken there is no FTP API in Android directly, but you could use the apache one. it works as well. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method of image loading:

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Let me know if it works.