# Chunk Download is Possible in Android FTP?

Tags: android, http, ftp, ftps

I am Using FTPS and downloading Files into the device. All this is working good and now my Challenge is to divide the file into equal sized chunks and then proceed the download. If the file size is 50MB then i can divide it as 10MB x 5 equal sized chunks. Can u give me some good examples for this? I am using HTTP,FTP and FTPS for file downloading.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may want to have a look at android FTP library.

Have a look at link below:
[Android FTP Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library)

Regards,
Bsengar

Comment: No Bsenger i dint ask for the FTP File Download in Android. My Question is using the same FTP Download Mechanism can u do a Chunked File Download? Means if the file size is 50MB, i have to divide the file into five 10MB Files and Download that Five Files seperately. Later i have to merge all the chunks to make it as a single file. Just like what Download Managers doing.. U got me?