# Android FTP from URL

Tags: android, ftp

I need to download a set of files from server via ftp.  For example say ftp://ftp.example.co.uk/folder1/textfile1

I cant seem to find much information about using ftp and android.  Can in be done in the same way as an http network request http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

If not, can someone point me to a tutorial on how to do so.

Comment: you can use [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) for FTP in the same way as it is in your link

Comment: Read this [thread ][1][1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered formatting your file to base64 and creating a web service to handle the request?

Comment: and what for? HTTP support binary files, so there is no need to waste CPU cycles and memory for encoding/decoding binary to/from base64