# Android online data save

Tags: android, android-activity

which method is the best for store some text data online? I'm beginner and I am making an app that has SQLite database but it works only locally. I need to store data like choosing option online. How to do it best?

Answer (score 0):

I found it most simple to just use ftp for uploading text files to my web server from my app. An explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library) for using Apache Commmons for this purpose.

Comment: I saw that, but if I have for ex. 1000 questions and for all of them number of clicks it should be harder to get data then from database.

Answer (score 0):

Hope so it help alot

http://sampleprogramz.com/android/mysqldb.php

add insert/update/delete php file in htdocs folder in XAMMP OR

add these file in WWW folder in WAMMP

make sure XAMMP/WAMMP are correctly running.

if u unable to do just exit skype and restart XAMMP AND WAMMP