# FTP Android download, write and upload

Tags: android, ftp, android-service

I'm begginer of Android. I'm making app that downloads file from FTP server, writes to it some date and then upload updated file to FTP server. I used apache library for FTP downloading and uploading. How to direct just downloaded file from FTP to write to it ?

```
  try {
        client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect("192.168.0.13", 21);
        client.login("user", "user");
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        client.retrieveFile("date", /*what here*/);



        /*other code*/

    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

It is possible not to save file on any kind of storage, but only keep it in app ?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567601/android-ftp-library
Hope it may be useful

Comment: Maybe clue is to find way to convert OutPutStream to InPutStream ?

Comment: Anyone help, I can't deal with it