# Text from FTP server into TextView

Tags: java, android, apache, ftp

I'm trying to show text from a FTP server into a textView. The code itself doesn't show errors, but when I run the app the textView is blank. The FTP server doesn't require login. And yes I have added Internet permission to the manifest file. Furthermore I have implemented Apache IOutilis to convert inputStream to String.

I think the code is not complete, but I have no clue what I have to add to make it work.

This is what I have at the moment:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView textOutput;
    public String string;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textOutput = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        FTPdownload ftPdownload = new FTPdownload();
        ftPdownload.execute();

    }

    private class FTPdownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            try {
                ftpClient.connect("ftp.mysite.com");
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("working_directory");

                InputStream inStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("file.txt");
                string = IOUtils.toString(inStream, UTF_8);

                ftpClient.disconnect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void Str) {
            textOutput.setText(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

(I'm aware of the memory leak in the AsynTask class, but I know how to fix that)

**EDIT:** debug output

```js
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2440)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:1084)
        at com.example.ftp.MainActivity$FTPdownload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
        at com.example.ftp.MainActivity$FTPdownload.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it for weather your "string" is getting any value or not?

Comment: I updated the post above with a debug output.

Comment: I am afraid you are not able to establish the FTP connection properly, please check your FTP address/IP and port details. Also, here is a simple solution for FTP connection.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651337/4323999

Comment: @ankitpurwar A bit late, but it's finally working. As you said, the FTP connection was not set properly.

Comment: Glad it helped.