# Transfer file using LAN between Android and Windows PC

Tags: android, ip, file-transfer, lan

How can I transfer file with the use of IP address in the same LAN between Android and Windows PC through Lan cable and Wifi.

I have tried in google but getting some Javascript code, i didn't get Android/Java code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which network file sharing protocols did you research?

Comment: @MorrisonChang currently i am looking for FTP Protocol.

Comment: So you didn't find [Android FTP library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1567601/295004)? Or any other open source library?

Comment: @MorrisonChang  Can you suggest what is the best way to achieve this functionality Or sample link. We need to do this without internet connection.

Comment: As you need `an internet connection` for communication, your statement is unclear. You should update your question with the limitations placed on your environment, like "between a PC, a WiFI router with no internet and an Android device" or other configuration. Or explain what you've tried and what doesn't work. I remind you that asking for tutorials or other libraries is off-topic.